Sync CSS with Audio Loud Noise via Javascript
I am totally a non-musical person and I have no idea how to find a solution for this. I have a simple CSS animation that I want to fire via Javascript every time a thunder (peak of the sound bar) is detected in the audio playing in the background.
I have found all sorts guides with javascript regarding audio sync, but they all relate to creating global audio bars for the whole background noise, while I just want for one particular one.
CSS Animation:
<style> 
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: relative;
animation: mymove 5s 1 ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes mymove {
from {top: 0px;}
to {top: 200px;}
}
</style>

<div></div>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
new Audio("./070115-glorious-early-morning-t-storm-19045.mp3").play();
};
</script>

Audio Track: https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/070115-glorious-early-morning-t-storm-19045/
Thank you!

Using the AudioContent you can analyze the audio data in real-time by AnalyserNode with audioContext.createAnalyser();, where you check if the threshold of the audio ( at this moment ) exceeds a specific value, then run the animation.


window.onload = async function() {
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const audioElement = new Audio("./070115-glorious-early-morning-t-storm-19045.mp3");
    const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    track.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
    audioElement.play();

    function detectThunder() {
        const dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
        let maxVal = Math.max(...dataArray) - 128;

        if (maxVal > 25) { // Threshold for "loud" noise, adjust as needed
            document.getElementById('animatedDiv').classList.add('thunder');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('animatedDiv').classList.remove('thunder');
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(detectThunder); // Keep looping to check sound
    }

    detectThunder();
};
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: mymove;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused; /* Initially paused */
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
}

.thunder {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
<div id="animatedDiv"></div>




For both solutions I get this exact error: The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence. I did enable autoplay in Firefox, so I am unsure where the issue is. I am running the html page locally on my PC.

It seems that createMediaElementSource does not operate in the absence of http(s) because I was running the path from file:///.

@user1286956, Yes, Great to know that it works for you.

To do this, you'll need to analyze the audio data in real-time to detect peaks and then trigger the CSS animation, which you can do with AudioContext. I have console.log() your Peak, which is more than 17. And also according to the new browser policy, the user must first interact with the DOM before playing any Audio element. So that's Why I have also used click EventListener to make it work.
Styling part:
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}

.animate {
  animation: mymove 0.5s 1 ease-in-out;
}

HTML part:
<div id="thunder-box"></div>

JavaScript part:
window.onload = function() {
  const thunderBox = document.getElementById('thunder-box');
  thunderBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Thunder box clicked');
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const audioElement = new Audio("sound.mp3"); // replace your own sound url
    const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    track.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 256;
    const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    audioElement.play();
    console.log('Audio playing');

    const detectPeaks = () => {
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        sum += dataArray[i];
      }
      const average = sum / bufferLength;
      console.log('Average frequency value:', average);
      if (average >= 17) { // Adjust this threshold based on the audio
        console.log('Peak detected');
        triggerAnimation();
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(detectPeaks);
    };

    const triggerAnimation = () => {
      console.log('Triggering animation');
      thunderBox.classList.remove('animate');
      // Trigger a reflow, flushing the CSS changes
      void thunderBox.offsetWidth;
      thunderBox.classList.add('animate');
    };

    detectPeaks();
  }, { once: true });
};

Hope it helps.

For both solutions I get this exact error: The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence. I did enable autoplay in Firefox, so I am unsure where the issue is. I am running the html page locally on my PC.

Ah it seems that createMediaElementSource does not operate in the absence of http(s). I was running the path from file:///. it is far more complicated than I thought to achieve this script, thank you for your help, you are the best!
